# Php Api html reponse display data issue using php

Tags: php, json

I am using an api to get scorecard of matches using php, response is coming from api as text/html so I conveted this response to json using json_encode first and then converted to json_decode for display but I am not getting matchId wise results.

```
API RESPONSE HEADERS
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 13:36:11 GMT
Server: Mashape/5.0.5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
```

demo: [click here](http://melob.orgfree.com/)

var_dump($response);

Code Here

```
$html = json_encode($response);
$json = json_decode($html);

foreach($json as $data => $value)
{
echo $value->matchId;
}
```

above var_dump giving response, foreach loop printing nothing.

demo link scroll page at bottom you should see '------------' this message. foreach loop print start here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify if you want to get an associative array and not an object from `json_decode` . Therefore, you should use

```
json_decode($response, true)
```

For more information see [here](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: Is the output of the `var_dump($response)` the one we see in the link you provided? Because if it is it should work.

Comment: Hi can you tell me it is working but some scrap values also coming how do i get only values

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Maybe provide your current output?